# Server response when user was authenticated

Tags: authentication, server, response

I am poking around client-server communication, and I am stuck on a problem, where I don't know what the server should respond with, when the user authentication has been successful, or not. Do I want to respond with just a "True" or "False", or are there more intricate responses when designing a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can return

```
 {"state":500, "msg":"auth failed"}
```

for interfaces that need that auth. And return actual data

```
{"data":{"twits":[...]}}
```

for non-auth-required interfaces